# Azure Function App URL and API managment Gateway URL

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I have set up a function app on azure, and I have also set up API management part. I want to get logs when I access the function app URL on a browser, However, Currently I am getting logs when I access the Gateway URL. Is it possible to get logs by accessing the funciton app URL instead of Gateway URL?

I have set the API's section in API management part, what can i do so that I get logs accessing the function app URL not the Gateway URL
[API settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAqzf.png)

Comment: You have diag logs on the APIM but want them on the function app too? You can add diag logs to the function app as well. It sounds like you should just set them to go to the same log workspace as the APIM.

Comment: I am getting logs now, thank you, any possibility I can make the logs bit cleaned up? like is there like policy or something

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to us and raising this issue. To enable the Diagnostic Logs for the function app you can follow the below steps:

1. Navigate to your Azure Function APp in the Azure Portal.
2. Click on **Diagnostic Settings** and then select **Add Diagnostic setting** as shown below:

[image]
3. You can send the Function App logs to various destinations. I would recommend you selecting Log Analytics Workspace since it provides flexibility to query your logs easily:
[image]

4. If you want to view the logs, you can navigate to the LogAnalytics workspace and then select the Logs option and run the query as explained in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp#querying-the-logs) article:
   [image]

Alternatively you can also enable the Application Insights logs as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/analyze-telemetry-data#view-telemetry-in-application-insights). Then you can view the logs by running the query as shown below:

[image]

From Function App side, you can view the Application Insights logs using Log Stream too:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting logs in event hub. But my end goal is to get these function app logs in METLO. What changes do I have to make and where so that I can get these logs to metlo ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since you mentioned that you’re already sending your Function App logs to Event Hubs, You can try writing a custom application that reads from Event Hubs and writes it to METLO. Alternatively, you can check the METLO’s documentation or support for specific instructions on how to ingest data from external sources like Azure Event Hubs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this information,but could you please let me know a little bit more about the custom application part? Few steps to achieve this custom application part. Do we have to build it inside the azure portal ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The application can be in Azure or onpremise. Its upto you. You can create an application(in programming language of your choice) which [reads the events from partitions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample05_ReadingEvents.md#read-events-from-all-partitions) and then write(send) it to METLO.

For more info about sample code, refer [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples).

Comment: Thank you, I will try implementing this.

Comment: One more question, can this be done for other applications as well? Like not just function app, can we apply this whole sending logs to metlo for other applications as well?

Comment: You need to check the METLO’s documentation or METLO's support for specific instructions on how to ingest data from external sources. If METLO's have any SDK which will help you write an application to pull data (logs) from Azure resources.